# Pandas concat does not handle Timestamp columns correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When two dataframes are concatenated (using concat) by default concat creates a new dataframe with the union of the columns of both, setting the values of any missing columns in the result with nan.  For example...

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(5), 'B':range(5)})
b = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(5)})
pd.concat([a , b], sort=False)

    A   B
0   0   0.0
1   1   1.0
...
3   3   NaN
4   4   NaN
```

But if the missing column in one of the dataframes contains timestamps this breaks...

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(5), 'B':[pd.Timestamp.utcnow() for _ in range(5)]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(5)})
pd.concat([a , b], sort=False)
```

Throws "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_can_consolidate'".

Python 3.6.5; Pandas 0.23; Windows 7 x64

Is this is known issue?
Are they're any workarounds known?

Comment: Yes, I think it was identified and fixed for v0.24 (see this issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22796). No obvious workarounds. Try converting to string first.

Comment: manually assigning `NaT` columns first is a potential workaround, e.g. `pd.concat([a, b.assign(B=pd.NaT)], sort=False)`

Comment: @root Well, that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, this is a known issue (see [GH22796](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22796)) and is fixed for version 0.24. In the meantime, there are two possible workarounds.

One is to convert to string:

```
df = pd.concat([a.assign(B=a.B.astype(str)), b], sort=False) 
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'], errors='coerce')
df

   A                          B
0  0 2018-12-06 18:21:35.363477
1  1 2018-12-06 18:21:35.363728
2  2 2018-12-06 18:21:35.363740
3  3 2018-12-06 18:21:35.363748
4  4 2018-12-06 18:21:35.363756
0  0                        NaT
1  1                        NaT
2  2                        NaT
3  3                        NaT
4  4                        NaT
```

The other, as @root mentioned, is to initialise an empty column in `b`:

```
pd.concat([a, b.assign(B=pd.NaT)], sort=False)

   A                                 B
0  0  2018-12-06 18:21:35.363477+00:00
1  1  2018-12-06 18:21:35.363728+00:00
2  2  2018-12-06 18:21:35.363740+00:00
3  3  2018-12-06 18:21:35.363748+00:00
4  4  2018-12-06 18:21:35.363756+00:00
0  0                               NaT
1  1                               NaT
2  2                               NaT
3  3                               NaT
4  4                               NaT
```